# Why Does Swift print "Optional(455 bytes)"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on a weather app, and trying to get the data from an API. But when I type in a city name and hit enter, Swift prints out a message "Optional(455 bytes)" Not sure what goes wrong.

```
import Foundation

protocol WeatherServiceDelegate{
    func setWeather(weather:Weather)
}

class WeatherService{
    var delegate: WeatherServiceDelegate?

    func getWeather(city: String){
        let path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Boston"
        let url = URL(string: path)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data:Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            print(data)
        }

        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong, what you are trying to do is, print an iOS encoded `Data` from a optional variable `data` of type `Data?`

You should rather be checking the response after decoding it.

Cheers!

Comment: You r right, I thought I will get some raw data from the api. I was just being stupid. Thank you so much

Comment: how would one check the response please?

Comment: @Matian2049 You can use something like this `var dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)`

Answer (score 5):

oh so here's the decoding part, in case anyone are still looking for it.

```
    if let data = data,
        let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) {
        print(urlContent)
    } else {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`data` is of optional type `Data?`. In Swift, you can unwrap optionals like this:

```
    if let data = data {
        print(data)
    }
```

This will mean that inside the if statement data is no longer an optional type and is of type `Data`. Since it has been unwrapped, it will no longer print the "Optional()" text in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so since you are assigning a value to data you exclude the chance of it remaining = nil. So you can use data! to automatically unwrap the value :

`let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data:Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        print(data!)
    }`